# CORS issue React Axios

Tags: reactjs, axios

I am trying to get a login screen to work on React, still new to this stuff. I have finally gotten requests to at least partially work, but now I am getting this error

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:5000/login' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource
```

I read a few articles and came across this one https://medium.com/@dtkatz/3-ways-to-fix-the-cors-error-and-how-access-control-allow-origin-works-d97d55946d9

Which says to use this code

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://localhost:3000
```

But I am not sure exactly where this line of code should go.

Comment: You can also "bypass" CORS checks in the browser(Chrome). You can disable security on Chrome and run the code on this disabled Chrome window.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe this needs to be fixed on the API. I'm not sure what you're hosting on your API on, but if it's [express](https://expressjs.com/), then doing something like:

```js
const cors = require('cors');

app.use(cors());
```

Alternatively, for testing purposes, you can install cors plugins on chrome and firefox.